# Use parameter as part of the url and how to handle it on django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, get

Noob question here.

I have an endpoint configure in this way

```
router.register(r'company-to-audit', myapp_views.CompanyToAuditViewSet,
                base_name='company-to-audit')
```

and on views.py

```
class CompanyToAuditViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...
   @list_route(methods=['get'], url_path=r'companies')
   def get_companies(self, request, **kwargs):
   # Lots of logic, return a json with Response
  return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Currently, to call this endpoint, I need 3 parameters. One of them is mandatory, City, and the other two are optional.
so, the calls look like this

```
http://localhost:8001/company-to-audit/companies/?city=Austin
```

or

```
http://localhost:8001/company-to-audit/companies/?city=Austin&codeID=3&regulation=oldest
```

How can I modify this so instead of using those URL, could use the following ones:

```
http://localhost:8001/company-to-audit/Austin
```

or

```
http://localhost:8001/company-to-audit/Austin/?codeID=3&regulation=oldest
```

So, basically, transform the mandatory City in part of the URL. And also, currently, I obtaining the parameters with request.query_params, for example

```
request.query_params.get('city')
```

If it is possible to transform City in part of the URL, how can I capture the value?

Answer (score 0):

in `@list_route`, you can change `url_path` to `companies/(?P<city>[^/.]+)`

then in view you can do it in these ways:

```
def get_companies(self, request, **kwargs):
   kwargs.get("city")
```

```
def get_companies(self, request, city="<default>", **kwargs):
    city # access like a variable
```

```
def get_companies(self, request, **kwargs):
     self.kwargs.get("city")
```